# Can a SyncAdapter modify RawContacts added by another SyncAdapter?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

If a SyncAdapter A for Account A creates a raw contact in the ContactsContract.RawContacts table, can SyncAdapter B for Account B update the RawContact added by SyncAdapter A.

Of particular interest is the sync1 or any of the sync fields in the raw contacts table?

If this is possible what are the possible issues that might arise as a result.

Can anyone show a sample of how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no per-contact-permission-model on the `Contacts` DB, every app and every `SyncAdapter` with the `Contacts` permission can read/write to any field in any contact.

However, the `syncX` fields under `RawContact` are used for proprietary purposes by the owning `SyncAdapter` (e.g. to keep track on what contact requires syncing, which one is dirty, when was it last synced, the backend-contact-id value, etc.), so make sure you don't touch anything you don't know what it's for, or you might risk corrupting some contacts.

To modify the `Sync1` value on `RawContact` with id `1234`, do:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(RawContacts.SYNC1, "Hello World");
cr.update(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values, RawContacts._ID + "=" + 1234, null);
```

**UPDATE - batch updates**

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withSelection(RawContacts._ID + "=" + 1234, null)
      .withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, "Hello")
      .build());
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withSelection(RawContacts._ID + "=" + 5678, null)
      .withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, "World")
      .build());

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot marmor, i was wondering how these updates can be done in a batch operation as recommended by google using the an ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ? If the sync colums are not the best place to place markers for alien syncadapters where do you think markers can be placed in the contactscontract.rawcontacts table ?

Comment: batch example added to answer